# Get "GET" parameters with Symfony HttpFoundation component

Tags: php, symfony

I've started using SymfonyHttpFoundation Component in my projects ( not otherwise on Symfony) and have troubles retrieving GET values.

The relevant code is:

```
$Request=Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request::createFromGlobals();
\Dev\Debug::dump($Request->query->get('action'));
```

This gets me a NULL ( \Dev\Debug::dump() is just a formatted wrapper for print_r)

The requested URL is:

```
http://[domainName]/compile.php?action=assets
```

The weird thing is 'though ( or maybe I am missing the point of the component) that is I create the Request ($Request=Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request::createFromGlobals()), the requested URL doesn't show the get string anymore, it becomes:

```
http://[domainName]/compile.php
```

My question is - why is it returning a NULL value and why the GET parameters are removed from the URL?

Comment: Seems good to me. `var_dump($_GET['action']);` is also null?

Comment: @Leggendario Yeah, also NULL and Notice- undefined index "action". If I comment out symfony Request, $_GET['action'] gets the value fine, of course.

Comment: `Request::createFromGlobals()` doesn't change `$_GET`. I think that the problem lies somewhere else. Can you post a few code to reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, guys, problem solved. Went mad and this line escaped my sight:

```
header('location:http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/compile.php');
```

Obviously it was simply redirecting, without me noticing. 
And I simply jumped to conclusions that the new thing should be at fault.

Http Component working fine.